# Jquery Datatable Functions Not Working After Data Loading Using Angular JS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Angular Module

```
var MeasureSettingsApp = angular.module("MeasureSettingsApp", [])
```

Angular Controller To load data to Data Table

```
MeasureSettingsApp.controller("measureSettingsCtrl", function ($scope, measureSettingsService) {$scope.GetAllMeasureSettingsDetails = function () {
         var getMeasureSettingsdata = measureSettingsService.getAllMeasureSettingsDetails();
        getMeasureSettingsdata.then(function (measuresettings) {
            $scope.MeasureSettingsModels = measuresettings.data;

        }, function () {
            alert('Error Occured While Getting Records');
        });
    }});
```

CHTML

```
able id="MeasureSettingsDetailsTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Setting Id</th>
                                    <th>Basic Measure</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Raw Material</th>
                                    <th>Measure</th>
                                    <th>Volume</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr data-ng-repeat="measureSettings in MeasureSettingsModels">
                                    <td>{{measureSettings.MeasureSettingsId}}</td>
                                    <td>{{measureSettings.BasicMeasureName}}</td>
                                    <td> Per 01 </td>
                                    <td>{{measureSettings.RawMaterialName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{measureSettings.MeasureName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{measureSettings.Volume}}</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="measureSettings.IsActive" disabled="disabled" /></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="EditMeasureSettings(measureSettings)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="DeleteMeasureSettings(measureSettings)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Setting Id</th>
                                    <th>Basic Measure</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Raw Material</th>
                                    <th>Measure</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Jquery Call For Data Table

```
$(function () {
        // $("#CategoryDetailsTable").DataTable();
        $('#MeasureSettingsDetailsTable').DataTable({

            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false
        });
    });
```

Data loading through angular ng-repeat works fine. rows also appear in jquery data table ,but end of the table always displaying **No Data Available In Table**,and if i click sorting button all ng-repeat rows are suddenly disappear. but when i static the data in data table using like `<tr> <td> some data </td> </tr>` it works completely fine

Comment: You cannot render a dataTable with `ng-repeat`, simple as that. If you want you will need to use angular dataTables (directives for jQuery datatables) or render by the dataTable itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in sort functionality. When you set array equal to something you break Angular reference and it thinks that this is new object...

When you work with angular array you should reset it length and push new values.

```
var getMeasureSettingsdata = measureSettingsService.getAllMeasureSettingsDetails();
getMeasureSettingsdata.then(function (measuresettings) {
   $scope.MeasureSettingsModels.length = 0;
   $scope.MeasureSettingsModels.push(measuresettings.data);
}, function () {
   alert('Error Occured While Getting Records');
});
```

Don't forget to update you sort function.